# Lighttpd + https installation with Self Signed Certificate

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, lighttpd, self-signed

on the following link tutorial is related with installation of https on lighttpd web server.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-to-install-ssl-lighttpd-https-configuration.html

my question is how can I generate these certificate with using any Self-Signed Certificate generator? I use self signed certificates for development purposes..

Answer (score 3):

First generate a key:

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out testing.key 2048
```

You can leave the password blank if this isn't going to be used for a publicly accessible web server. (ie localhost only)

Then generate a certificate signing request:

```
openssl req -new -key testing.key -out testing.csr
```

Then generate a certificate:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in testing.csr -signkey testing.key -out testing.crt
```

At this point you should have 3 files: `testing.key`,`testing.csr`, and `testing.crt`

To create a .pem file that lighttpd can use, concatenate your key and certificate:

```
cat testing.key testing.crt > certificate.pem
```

You can save the certificate in /etc/lighttpd/ssl or some such directory.